# How to auto generate generic response model from json in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, object, dart, serialization

I want to do a Flutter functionnality which take a json and generate a response model but without creating an object before.
For example, this is a json

```
{
   "result":[
      {
         "title":"ABC",
         "types":[
            "XXX",
            "XXX"
         ],
         "image":{
            "type":"image",
            "value":null
         },
         "comment":{
            "type":"large_text",
            "value":null
         },
         "date_creation":{
            "type":"date",
            "value":null
         },
         "audio_record":{
            "type":"audio",
            "value":null
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

And I want to generate this :

```
class Result{
  String _title;
  List<String> _types;
  ImageModel _image;
  CommentModel _comment;
  AudioRecorderModel _captureAudio;
  DateModel _dateCreation;

  Result(result) {
    _title = result['title'];
    _types = result['types'].cast<String>();
    _image = ImageModel.fromJson(result['image']);
    _comment = CommentModel.fromJson(result['comment']);
    _dateCreation = DateModel.fromJson(result['date_creation']);
    _captureAudio = AudioRecorderModel.fromJson(result['capture_audio']);
  }

  String get title => _title;
  List<String> get types=> _types;
  ImageModel get image => _image;
  CommentModel get comment => _comment;
  AudioRecorderModel get captureAudio => _captureAudio;
  DateModel get dateCreation => _dateCreation;
}
```

But without knowing how the result object look like before.

I hope I was clear :)

Thanks !

Comment: This might help - https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JigarPatel. I will look into it !